# How to do cursor:pointer in group-hover Tailwind Css?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have been trying to change cursor on group-hover like this,

```
<nav class="bg-indigo-800 flex justify-center w-screen">
        <div class="mt-2 flex justify-between items-center w-11/12 h-16 bg-gradient-to-t">
            <div class="w-16">
                <img class="w-full" src="./images/Logo.png" alt="logo">
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <div class="group-hover:border-white group-hover:hover:cursor-pointer mb-1 w-6 border-t-2"></div>
                <div class="group-hover:border-white group-hover:hover:cursor-pointer mb-1 w-6 border-t-2"></div>
                <div class="group-hover:border-white group-hover:hover:cursor-pointer mb-1 w-6 border-t-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

But it's not supported  guess,
So is there any alternate way to do that?

Comment: Did you add the variant for your wished utilities into your config file ? https://v1.tailwindcss.com/docs/pseudo-class-variants#group-hover

Comment: My previous' comment solution is not working, could you rather just put the `cusor-pointer` on the div with the `group` class ? I mean, if you want to have all the divs with a cursor inside of it, you could basically pass it to the parent. Otherwise, I tried some stuff but it looks like you should rely on JS here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `hover:cursor-pointer` where you want to get the pointer on hover it will solve